# UIKit: `popViewController` with completion block

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, poptoviewcontroller

I've been searching for a solution for this since yesterday. Everything I could find was suggested 4-5 iOS versions ago, and seems to not work anymore. I was wondering if anyone has a new, working idea?

Adding the two different suggestions I found:

```
func popViewController(animated: Bool, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
      popViewController(animated: animated)
      if animated, let coordinator = transitionCoordinator {
          coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
             completion()
          }
      } else {
          completion()
      }
}
```

And

```
func popViewControllerWithHandler(completion: ()->()) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
        self.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        CATransaction.commit()
}
```

What's the reason `UIKit` doesn't offer it? So weird

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you can conform your controller class to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and implement `didShow ViewController` method:

```
class YourController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate ...
```

in viewDidLoad set navigation controller delegate to self

```
navigationController?.delegate = self
```

after that use navigation controller didShow method like that:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    // your completion code here
    print("completion block")
 }
```